# Google Maps link for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, maps, apple-maps

I want to have a link to a Google Map on our company mobile website. The problem is, if I make a link, it takes you to the Google Maps website. It needs to open up the app.

I have found out that if you start the url with "comgooglemaps://" it will open google maps. However, this poses the problem that if a iOS user does not have Google Maps installed the link will not work.

Is there a way to open Google Maps if it is installed, but open the browser if not (I don't believe you can open Apple Maps from a website due to the nature of their API)

Thanks

EDIT: Just a heads up, this is being done on a website, not an app. So it needs to be done through HTML, Javascript, PHP etc. NOT a programing language.

Comment: Javascript and PHP are programing languages.

Comment: Did you ever solve this. I hae the same requirement?

Comment: As of 2018 you can use Google Maps URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50413036/5140781

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Apple Maps Links page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html).

Basically you link to maps.apple.com and it redirects to Google Maps if needed. Here's an example from the page:

http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino

With latitude, longitude and zoom:

http://maps.apple.com/?ll=53.01,6.01&z=15

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a)

You can use this method with url scheme for google map app. (comgooglemaps://blahblah)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:(NSURL*)foo]
```

It will return BOOL value.

Comment: What language is that? This needs to be done on a website, not an app

Comment: check another solution that i wrote

Answer (score 0):

Try this to move google map and set route

```
NSString* addr = nil;
     addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", destinationLat,destinationLong];

NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,%@",@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=",@"75.14524",@"12.1521"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    }
```