# Cordova iOS launch comgooglemaps fail

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-urls

I have a small problem.
I use comgooglemaps scheme to call google maps and perform a search.
This works ok but problem is if user don't have a google maps installed.

Now... how can i check this and if google maps are not installed to call google via browser?
... or to call some other maps app that user uses?

Thanx!

Comment: See https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator - the source code may help you

Comment: tnx, ill check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) that provides universal cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps. Currently this is recommended and supported way to open Google Maps app.

According to the documentation

> On an iOS device:
>
> - If Google Maps app for iOS is installed, the URL launches Google Maps in the Maps app and performs the requested action.
> - If the Google Maps app is not installed, the URL launches Google Maps in a browser and performs the requested action.

This behavior is pretty much what you were asking about, so replace comgooglemaps scheme with Google Maps URL (e.g. `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&parameters`) and you are settled.

I hope this helps!